# Как найти wndproc в ollydbg?

Tags: windows

Как найти wndproc в ollydbg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы это сделал по-другому: Выдвинул гипотезы о том какие Win-API функции могут регистрировать оконную. Далее с помощью Hiew посмотрел список импортируемых АПИ и посмотрел их там. Если файл запакован, то стаб пакера может сам находить апи-шки, тогда "сушите весла" или "приготовьтесь к улучшению знаний".

Пример когда все открыто:
1) Открыли файл в Hiew. Перешли в режим кода или хекса. Нажали F8 чтобы увидеть PE-заголовок, нажали F7 чтобы увидеть список импорта. Набрали первые буквы фунции к примеру Regist увидим:

> ```
> 0 RegisterClassA             │  USER32.DLL
> ```

2) Нажали Enter и перешли по месту ее вызова:

```
.00401EF9: E82E340100           call  LoadCursorA --↓2
.00401EFE: 8985CCFEFFFF         mov   [ebp][-000000134],eax
.00401F04: 33C0                 xor   eax,eax
.00401F06: 8985D0FEFFFF         mov   [ebp][-000000130],eax
.00401F0C: 33D2                 xor   edx,edx
.00401F0E: 8995D4FEFFFF         mov   [ebp][-00000012C],edx
.00401F14: C785D8FEFFFF036A4100 mov   d,[ebp][-000000128],000416A03 ;'OLLY2TEST'
.00401F1E: 8D8DB4FEFFFF         lea   ecx,[ebp][-00000014C]
.00401F24: 51                   push  ecx
.00401F25: E820340100           call  RegisterClassA --↓4
```

3) Теперь можем открыть OllyDbg и поставить бряк по выполнению на адрес .00401F25